# SQL Server vs MySQL and PHP vs ColdFusion

Tags: php, sql, coldfusion

This query works fine with ColdFusion, yet I can't get it to work in PHP. The PHP doesn't like my joins. What is different in the two queries?

```
<cfquery name="getArt" datasource="mssqlcf_PDartist1">
select * from artwork a
join Categories b on (b.CID = a.CID)
join SubCategories c on (c.CID = b.CID and c.SCID = a.SCID)
where AID = #AID#
order by DisplayOrder
</cfquery>


<?php
$dbname = 'pdartist2';
$table = 'artwork';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from artwork") or die(mysql_error());
a join Categories b on (b.CID = a.CID)
join SubCategories c on (c.CID = b.CID and c.SCID = a.SCID)
where AID = $AID
order by DisplayOrder
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: PHP does not care about your joins. ;)

Comment: Do you mean they need to be left out?

Comment: No I mean that PHP (or ColdFusion, for that matter) sends *strings* to the database server. It does not care in the least whether they contain joins or not.

Comment: So why does the query work on my Cold Fusion site and not on the PHP site? Could it be that PHP is case sensitive and Cold Fusion is not. Since the tables are named in all lowercase!?

Comment: Because you have a PHP syntax error right there. This has nothing to do with SQL. Mark's answer points that out very nicely.

Comment: I corrected the table names to lower case and I am back in business, or making progress anyway. The Cold Fusion to PHP conversion has really caused me some grief. Plus I had to convert the database from MySQL to SQL Server.

Comment: Table name case is completely irrelevant. If things started to work it's not because you've changed *that*. Also, I'm not sure why you're switching the platform. ColdFusion is nice, free implementations are available, what's the point in converting it all to PHP?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5379/discussion-between-the-old-dog-and-tomalak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ended the PHP string too early. The quotes must surround the entire SQL query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
    FROM artwork a
    JOIN Categories b ON b.CID = a.CID
    JOIN SubCategories c ON c.CID = b.CID AND c.SCID = a.SCID
    WHERE AID = $AID
    ORDER BY DisplayOrder") or die(mysql_error());
```